# Numeric-style citation call-outs encased in round parentheses instead of square brackets, with custom makebst-made bibliography style

Tags: citing, custom-bib

I have made a custom bibliography style with the `makebst` utility, where i chose numerical in-text citations. The default style is apparently with square brackets around the citation number, but i need parentheses around the number.

My style is not compatible with the `natbib` package so the "change square to round" solution does not solve the problem.

Here is my [custom.bst](https://mega.nz/#!A5h3TTbL!jxpv1cx8mgQy7ejwV7_EqI_3XOxqX5sPAFud81PcH7U%22custom.bst%22) which i made to suit the needs of the American Journal of Clinical Nutrition.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\quad#1.}
\makeatother

  \begin{document}
    I want these square brackets to be parentheses\cite{Turner-McGrievy2015}, like this(1).

    \bibliographystyle{ajcn}
    \bibliography{library}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't that a job for `natbib`?

Comment: AFAIK my style is not compatible with the natbib package.

Comment: AFAIK? You tested that, right? I certainly cannot know it.

Comment: I tried \usepackage{natbib}, and it did not work at all.

Comment: Most packages need to be used, often in a special way. Just by loading a package, you cannot get the magic done. You have to tell `natbib` what you want and you (likely) want `\usepackage[round,numbers]{natbib}`

Comment: @Johannes_B - As my answer demonstrates, you're absolutely correct in your recommendation that `natbib` should be loaded with the options `round` and `numbers`. :-)

Comment: @Mico I know, i tried it out before leaving the comment ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My [makebst-produced bibliography] style is not compatible with the `natbib` package

You should check the correctness of this claim. The `custom-bib` package and its `makebst` utility were written by the person who also authored the `natbib` citation management package. As such, bespoke bibliography styles created with the `makebst` should generally be eminently compatible with `natbib`.

You should load the `natbib` package with the options `round` and `numbers`. Be sure to recompile twice in order to propagate all changes.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{library.bib} % create a dummy entry
@misc{Turner-McGrievy2015, author = "A", title = "B", year = 2015}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[round,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ajcn}  
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\quad#1.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
I want the fences around a citation call-out, e.g., 
\cite{Turner-McGrievy2015}, to be like ``(1)''.

\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```